# How can i design 6x4 meter area in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design

I have a 6x4 meter area. Adobe Illustrator doesn't support 6m Artboards. How can i design a 6x4 meter area in Adobe Illustrator?

Answer (score 5):

Because Illustrator is vector, so you can scale your graphics indefinitely. For this reason you don't need to make your artwork 1:1. Just make your graphic 2:1 or 10:1 and then label your file clearly that it is 2:1. *Don't forget to inform your client / printer of the ratio in an email too (always keep that clear paper trail just in case).*

The only consideration you need to make is if you add any raster images, in that case, scale them according to your scale (so if it's 2:1, make the DPI twice as high, remember that usually you don't need as high DPI when if the end product is this big). You mentioned in the comments that it's for an exhibition. Because of the size of the wall, I would suggest you have your 1:1 resolution at around 72-100 PDI if people will be viewing from 3-6ft away, however if people will get quite close (closer than 3ft), maybe use 150-200 dpi. *However, always ask your printer! They might advise you to use a certain DPI and you should always follow their advice.*

Comment: Thanks @consume. I have a lot of image. So  I should work 3meterX2meter area or 5.5meterX3.6meter :) for minimum make a mistake

Comment: No problem @user1942224, I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @consume. I have a lot of image. So I should work 3meterX2meter area or 5.5meterX3.6meter :) for minimum make a mistake

Comment: @user1942224 I would go 3x2, that way keeping the mesurements at half makes it easier to work things out in your head (or it is for me anyway). What is the end result, is it a banner / shop front / billboard?

Comment: It's a exhibition wall. I will send poster another country and they will print and stick. Should i write ratio value on our artwork for print works

Comment: @user1942224 yes, definitely add the ratio. Also check with them the optimum DPI for the end product and then double it for the 2:1 ratio.

Comment: I'm quite partial to 1:10 scale, purely because you can simply shift the decimal over when checking the dimensions. I also include the final dims in the filename just to play it safe; it makes it much quicker to preflight a document when the dims are right there in front of you.

Comment: @Dre you are definitely right. I'm going to work 540X360milimeter 1:10 scale.

Comment: @user1942224 did the file and the print all work out in the end?